# How do you setup and retrieve encryption and signing certificates in IIS for OpenIddict?

Tags: security, ssl, iis, certificate, openiddict

I am new to OpenIddict and authorization in general. I am having trouble storing and retrieving the encryption and signing certificates that will be used by OpenIddict. I will be deploying this as a production-ready app to IIS.

I would like to know how I would go about storing the certificates in IIS and then retrieving them in my app startup?
Here are the two methods I need to use in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
options.AddEncryptionCertificate();
options.AddSigningCertificate();
```

I created both of these certificates manually using [this code](https://documentation.openiddict.com/configuration/encryption-and-signing-credentials.html#registering-a-certificate-recommended-for-production-ready-scenarios), then writing them to .pfx files.

I then used the certificate import wizard to import the certificates to my host computer that is running IIS. But right now I am confused on how to retrieve these certificates from IIS storage when calling options.Add_Certificate(). Right now I can retrieve the certificate directly from the project folder but this seems quite unsafe to have the certificates sitting in the folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code get list of certificate.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates){
  //TODO's
 }
```

Then you can add certificate in the `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, I added and retrieved it from the X509 store. But now I'm getting `InvalidOperationException: The specified certificate doesn't contain the required private key.` when trying to retrieve the certificate from the store. I haven't added a private key for these certificates so I should be able to retrieve it without one. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the application pool identity you set?

Comment: I'm currently running from development so IIS application pool identity is not involved here, right?

Comment: You mean run it in visual studio? If so, please use this code to add certificate which in your project folder. Check  if it still reort this error.

Comment: Yes I am running it in visual studio. I have managed to create the certificates using OpenSSL instead as that allows me to include a private key. The certificates are now working when calling                         `options.AddEncryptionCertificate(GetEncryptionCertificate());
options.AddSigningCertificate(GetSigningCertificate());`

I'm going to see if it works on IIS now.

Comment: When you test it on IIS, one thing you need to set is application pool identity. It should have permission to read and write certificate. So it is better to set it to administrator or you can add app pool in security of certificate folder.

Comment: Yes that has been set. I found the problem - the computer did not have access to the certificate's private key. I had to click "Manage the private key", then I added the AppPool user to have access. Now it works. Thanks for your help!